# gradle add dependency like npm

Tags: gradle, npm, package-managers

I am using gradle for building my java apps

recently I realized that , npm (node package manager) has a simpler procedure for add anorher dependency (I mean this only takes a command like `npm install axios`) but in gradle for each dependency we have to go to that library repositiry and copy newest version plus full library name each time we want to
use that

is a way to use gradle like a way that npm does?
something like.`gradle dep add okhttp`

Comment: different way, I do not think you can add dependencies using gradle like this way. @AmirHossein Abdolmotallebi in java project, it would be many module and submodule, I did not hear using gradle add dependencies like this way.

Comment: ok so, is there any solution for simplify this process little more? like custom plugins  etc .. ?